# Trying to define a static constant variable in a class

Tags: c++, class, static

I am defining a variable `adc_cmd[9]` as a `static const unsigned char` in my class `ADC` under private. Since it is a constant I thought I would just define it inside the class it self, but that didn't work apparently:

```
#pragma once

class ADC{
private:
    static const unsigned char adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };
//...
};
```

**Error:**

```
error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before '{' token
error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const unsigned char [9]'
```

...

So I tried bringing the line out of the class with: `static const unsigned char ADC::adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };`, but that yielded this error:

```
error: 'static' may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member
error: 'const unsigned char ADC::adc_cmd [9]' is not a static member of 'class ADC'
```

I obviously am not declaring this properly. What is the correct way to declare this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *declare* it inside the class body:

```
class ADC{
private:
    static const unsigned char adc_cmd[9];
//...
};
```

and *define* (and initialize) it outside (just once, as for any external-linkage definition):

```
const unsigned char ADC::adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };
```

without writing `static`, as specified by the error message.

(don't ask me for an explanation of why here `static` is forbidden, I always found the various "repetition of qualifiers" rules completely illogic)

Answer (score 5):

In C++03, static data member definitions go *outside* of the class definition.

Header:

```
#pragma once

class ADC {
private:
    static unsigned char const adc_cmd[9];
};
```

In *one* .cpp file:

```
#include "headername"

unsigned char const ADC::adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine the two:

```
class ADC{
private:
    static const unsigned char adc_cmd[9];
    //...
};

//.cpp
const unsigned char ADC::adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to contribute to Matteo's answer:

We must point out that the `static` qualifier is indeed a bit confusing in C++. To my knowledge, it does three different things depending on where it is used:

1. In front of class member attributes: makes this attribute the same for all instances of that class (same as Java).
2. In front of a global variable: reduces the scope of the variable to the current source file only (same as C).
3. In front of a local variable within a method / function: makes this variable the same for all calls to that method / function (same as C, may be useful for the singleton design pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Since **C++11**, what you can do in a case like this (when you have a static const LiteralType) is use [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), making the value a guaranteed compile-time constant.

That would be:

```
#pragma once

class ADC{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned char adc_cmd[9] = { 0x87, 0xC7, 0x97, 0xD7, 0xA7, 0xE7, 0xB7, 0xF7, 0x00 };
//...
};
```